# How to delete item from core data swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data

I have application and I save user id in core data
now I want to know how to delete one element?
this is how I store data in core data, I want to delete it in another class, not the same class I store data on it

```
moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fav = UFav(context: moc)
    fav.idFav=Int16(UserID)
    do{
        try self.moc.save()
    } catch {
        print("Save id error")
    }
```

Comment: `Fetch` it, `delete` it, `save` the `context`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do when fetching, storing and deleting managed objects you do it by using your ManagedObjectContext instance so you can do it in any class as long as that class has access to your managed object context.

```
moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
moc.delete(fav) // or whatever your managed object is
```

Read up on the documentation for ManagedObjectContext and learn to understand its role in the Core Data stack.